# If a permutation is a cycle, can I factorize it as a product of disjoint cycles?

Tags: permutations, symmetric-groups

> Given $\sigma,\tau \in S_7$
>   $$\sigma=(123456),\, \tau=(123)(456)$$
>   write $\sigma \circ\tau$ as a product of disjoint cycles.

Now, $\sigma \circ \tau$ is $(132465)$. To my understanding it doesn't make sense to ask to break a cycle into disjoint cycles, so I'd answer $(132465)(7)$—abusing the notation for a cycle with $(7)$. Is that correct?

Also, what would have happened if the length of the cycle was $7$, such as $(1234567)$? In that case, how can I write that cycle as a product of disjoint cycles?

Comment: It may help to note that a single cycle can be thought of as a product of one cycle.

Comment: Natural numbers have a unique (*up to order and sign*) representation as a product of prime numbers, e.g. $20=2\cdot 2\cdot 5$ and $6=2\cdot 3$, one allows the representation to include only a single term as is the case with $3=3$ is the product of one prime.  In the same way some permutations will be written with only one cycle in the representation using products of disjoint cycles, and that is fine.